# Complex unknown date/time representation

Tags: mysql, datetime, reverse-engineering

Logfiles containing date/time in a weird format keeps me awake.
I did not manege to reverse engineer the used algorithm. Using DCode from www.digital-detective.co.uk did not work either. 
What I know: It is a 64 bit value and it starts at January 1, 1900.
Some examples:

> Date/time:          Hex-representation:
>       1900-01-01 00:00:00 > 0000000000000000
>       2006-07-19 00:00:00 > 0000000000A000E3
>       2008-04-14 00:00:00 > 00000000000050E3
>       2008-04-15 11:04:32 > 00D6CF74C42E50E3
>       2008-04-15 11:04:46 > 00CEA0C8C52E50E3
>       2008-04-15 11:08:32 > 00EC3B36DB2E50E3
>       2008-04-16 11:08:43 > 008B3B41DC4E50E3
>       2008-04-16 11:21:02 > 00B3AD52224F50E3
>       2012-02-21 00:00:00 > 00000000000000E4
>       2012-03-13 13:37:54 > 007A35F12CB202E4
>       2012-10-22 16:27:13 > 001F7A2AF0951EE4

Any idea how to convert a given value to a date/time to regain my sleep?

Comment: That's an interesting riddle, but I cannot solve it (besides the basic reverse reading). May I suggest to ask on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ . And keep us updated about the solution (after you get a good night of course!).

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you for sure that the value either needs to swap endianness or be reversed. You can see all the dates except for the EPOCH ending in `E3` and `E4`, where most of the other digits change a ton. You can also see times on 00:00:00 have flat zeroes across the left side, which further validates this claim.

I did some quick math, though, and it doesn't seem to be in terms of seconds, nanoseconds, microseconds, or anything else. There's definitely a linear correlation between the values, though. What I would do from here is generate a batch of times that are a few seconds apart and see how the value changes. This will help confirm if you need to reverse the digits or flip the endianness, as well as might hint in what relation the value is to a second.

EDIT: it's definitely an endianness flip, not a string reversal. If it was a reversal, it would have went `E3`->`F3`, not `E3`->`E4`. doh.

From here, I would generate times 100 seconds, 1000 seconds, and 10000 seconds after the EPOCH. This may give you an extra hint.

Comment: How do you say there is 'linear' correlation while 00000000000050E3 < 0000000000A000E3 ?

Comment: The way I am trying to decode using positional approach than considering them as numerics. My above comparison actually means "00000000000050" < "0000000000A000" by stripping the endians. But the dates they refer were 2008 and 2006 respectively.

Comment: My first reply to you was incorrect, you have thrown a wrench in a part of my theory, but not completely.

Btw, I don't think you know what endianness is. Swapping endiannes of these two numbers gives `E300A00000000000` and `E350000000000000`. You're basically reversing it on 2-digit pairs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 2):

Building on Nick Cano's answer, it appears the hex pairs need to be
read from right to left. You can convert the hex value to the date by taking the
following steps:

1. Reverse the hex value
2. Convert the hex value to bytes
3. Byte-swap: Unpack the bytes as big endian, then repack to bytes as little endian
4. Convert the hex value to an integer, `Int`.
5. Compute `Timestamp = A*Int + B`, where  `A = 2.45563569478691e-09` and `B = -39014179200.000061`
6. Convert `Timestamp` (seconds since the Epoch 1970-01-01) to a `Date`.

When these steps are applied to the posted data, this is the result:

```
              Datetime               Hex              RHex              Flip  \
0  1900-01-01 00:00:00  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000   
1  2006-07-19 00:00:00  0000000000A000E3  3E000A0000000000  E300A00000000000   
2  2008-04-14 00:00:00  00000000000050E3  3E05000000000000  E350000000000000   
3  2008-04-15 11:04:32  00D6CF74C42E50E3  3E05E24C47FC6D00  E3502EC474CFD600   
4  2008-04-15 11:04:46  00CEA0C8C52E50E3  3E05E25C8C0AEC00  E3502EC5C8A0CE00   
5  2008-04-15 11:08:32  00EC3B36DB2E50E3  3E05E2BD63B3CE00  E3502EDB363BEC00   
6  2008-04-16 11:08:43  008B3B41DC4E50E3  3E05E4CD14B3B800  E3504EDC413B8B00   
7  2008-04-16 11:21:02  00B3AD52224F50E3  3E05F42225DA3B00  E3504F2252ADB300   
8  2012-02-21 00:00:00  00000000000000E4  4E00000000000000  E400000000000000   
9  2012-03-13 13:37:54  007A35F12CB202E4  4E202BC21F53A700  E402B22CF1357A00   
10 2012-10-22 16:27:13  001F7A2AF0951EE4  4EE1590FA2A7F100  E41E95F02A7A1F00   

                     Int    Timestamp                 Date  
0                      0 -39014179200  0733-09-10 00:00:00  
1   16357249768470085632   1153267200  2006-07-19 00:00:00  
2   16379591844746493952   1208131200  2008-04-14 00:00:00  
3   16379643266054739456   1208257472  2008-04-15 11:04:32  
4   16379643271755910656   1208257486  2008-04-15 11:04:46  
5   16379643363789106176   1208257712  2008-04-15 11:08:32  
6   16379678552640686848   1208344123  2008-04-16 11:08:43  
7   16379678853581091584   1208344862  2008-04-16 11:21:02  
8   16429131440647569408   1329782400  2012-02-21 00:00:00  
9   16429890296696109568   1331645874  2012-03-13 13:37:54  
10  16437740548686225152   1350923233  2012-10-22 16:27:13
```

Note that the computed (last) `Date` column matches the given (first) `Datetime`
column except for `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. I'm guessing that MySQL inserted
`1900-01-01 00:00:00` as a default value for an invalid date.

The magic constants, A and B were found by applying linear regression to the data. Given the `Datetime`s, the corresponding `Timestamp` can be computed. Then A and B can be found by fitting the best-fit line through the `Timestamp`s versus the `Int`s.

Here is the python code I used to explore the problem and generate the table above:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import struct
import binascii

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0])

df['RHex'] = df['Hex'].str[::-1]

def flip_endian(x):
    xbytes = binascii.unhexlify(x)
    swapped = struct.pack('<8h', *struct.unpack('>8h', x))
    return swapped
df['Flip'] = df['RHex'].apply(flip_endian)

df['Int'] = df['Flip'].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))

# The constants were found by linear regression:
# import scipy.stats as stats
# df['Timestamp'] = (df['Datetime'] - pd.Timestamp('1970-1-1')).dt.total_seconds()
# A, B, rval, pval, stderr = stats.linregress(df['Int'], df['Timestamp'])
A, B = 2.45563569478691e-09, -39014179200.000061

df['Timestamp'] = (A*df['Int'] + B).astype(int)
df['Date'] = (np.array(['1970-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]') 
              + np.array(df['Timestamp'], dtype='timedelta64[s]')).tolist()

print(df)
```

Comment: Indeed, endianness was the answer, using that it turned out that the most right byte was splitted into two components. This multiplier was isolated using: set @a=conv(LEFT(HEX(substring(@RuweString,8,1)),1), 16,10) Where RuweString is the 8 byte word from the datasource.